# error with elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

This is an example in the Python book I'm reading. When I try to run the program there's an error, and when I check the code for the error `elif` is highlighted in red. I'm programming in Python 2.5.

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print "It is a number between 1 and 99. I'll give you six tries. "

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input("What's your guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print "Too low!"
        elif guess > secret:
            print "Too high"
            tries = tries + 1
            if guess == secret:
                print "Correct! You found my secret!"
                else:
                    print "No more guesses! Better luck next time!"
                    print "The secret number was", secret
```

Comment: Always specify what errors you get, as detailed as possible (e.g. copy the error message including traceback verbatim).

Comment: Also, it's spelled n00b.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133562/if-print-statement-repeated-lots-of-times/23133692#23133692 for a related question that I suspect may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is indentation sensitive.

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print "It is a number between 1 and 99. I'll give you six tries. "

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input("What's your guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print "Too low!"
    elif guess > secret:
        print "Too high"
        tries = tries + 1
    elif guess == secret:
        print "Correct! You found my secret!"
    else:
        print "No more guesses! Better luck next time!"
        print "The secret number was", secret
```

Edit: I know there are still bugs in this, such as `tries = tries + 1` which should be somewhere else in the code. But this version at least does not give syntax errors.

Comment: Felix hit it right on the money. Also make sure that whatever you are indenting by is consistent. If you use spaces, use the same number of spaces every time. If you use tabs. Use the same number of tabs every time. Never mix spaces and tabs as it will cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your indentation.

Instead of:

```
if foo:
    foobar()
    elif bar:
        barbaz()
```

It should be:

```
if foo:
    foobar()
elif bar:
    barbaz()
```

Fixed, your code would then look like this (note, I've also fixed your `else` at the end to work correctly):

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print "It is a number between 1 and 99. I'll give you six tries. "

while guess != secret:
    if tries < 6:
        guess = input("What's your guess? ")
        if guess < secret:
            print "Too low!"
        elif guess > secret:
            print "Too high"
            tries = tries + 1
        elif guess == secret:
            print "Correct! You found my secret!"
    else:
        print "No more guesses! Better luck next time!"
        print "The secret number was", secret
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.

1. The `elif` and `if` should have the same indentation level.
2. You only increment `tries` in the too-high case.
3. `input()` returns a string; you should convert it to an integer.
4. After testing `<` and `>`, the `==` is redundant.
5. Since `<`, `>` and `==` cover every case, you'll never reach the `else`:

Here's a reworking of the logic:

```
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input("What's your guess? "))
    if guess < secret:
        print "Too low!"
    elif guess > secret:
        print "Too high"
    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    print "Correct! You found my secret!"
else:
    print "No more guesses! Better luck next time!"
    print "The secret number was", secret
```