# if print statement repeated lots of times

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Why does the too low, too high and got it print repeatedly lots of times?

This is my code:

```
import random
name = input("Hello there! What's your name?\n")
print("Hello there", name, ". Welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER GAME")
number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
n=1
while n<10:
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")

    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")

    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")

    n=n+1
```

Comment: Would you care to correct the indentation of the code you posted? As you currently have it the code will simply complain about a syntax error and won't print anything.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the `guess` *inside* the loop, from:

```
guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
n=1
while n<10:
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")

    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")

    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")

    n = n+1
```

to:

```
n = 1
while n < 10:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")

    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")

    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")

    n += 1
```

Also, you can simplify with:

```
for _ in range(9):
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
    ...
```

And should `break` when the user makes a correct guess:

```
    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, they were not my own indents by the way!

Comment: Also,                                                         import random
name = input("Hello there! What's your name?\n")
print("Hello there", name, ". Welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER GAME")
number = random.randint(1,100)
n=1
while guess != number:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")

    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")

    else:        
        print("Got it")
        
    

    n= n+1      it says that guess is not indentified and I understand this but I do I indentify it where needed??

Comment: yeh I know sorry :( and how do I break?? sorry im not too good on python as you can probably tell!

Comment: Sorry - I should say that you *don't* need to `break` with your `while` loop - it will end when the `guess` is correct. You don't need the `n`, or the `else` (you can put `print("Got it")` *after* the loop), but will need to set `guess = 0` before the loop starts.

Comment: I woudn't use '`_`' since it's a reserved name that's automatically assigned to in interactive mode.

Comment: but I put guess = int(input("Please guess a number")) so why would I need to put guess = 0?? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev `_` is the convention for a variable you aren't using, and many people aren't even aware of `_`'s behaviour/use in the shell - it certainly isn't reserved

Comment: @user3545328 because you assign `guess` *inside the loop*, so the first time you arrive at the loop and evaluate `guess != number` it *isn't yet assigned*

Comment: @jonrsharpe - this still introduces side effects when experimenting/debugging (which is a widespread practive in Python) and thus is a problem for unsuspecting users. So I'm still positive it's undesirable in example code - without a note, at least.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Can you give a specific example of an undesirable side effect of using this convention?  I can't think of one.

Comment: @SethMMorton If you use the code with it in an interactive session, you'll get incorrect results when trying to view its current value. Futhermore, since this is example code, a copy-pasting/unsuspecting user may not bother to change the name and actually use it in the logic. It's effectively laying a land mine.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I asked for a specific example. Like code that I can paste into my interactive session to verify that what you say is true.  I understand your point, but in practice I don't believe that this will happen, because `_` will continuously be overwritten with each command, so manually setting `_` in the loop will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your real indentation ?

if yes:

```
while n<10:
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")
    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")
    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")
```

and the last `elif guess == number:` can be just `else` ;)

edit: and I have forgotten your  n++ and the real problem: the input

so:

```
while n<10:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
    n = n+1
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")
    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")
    else:
        print("Got it")
```

and to exit the loop:

```
while n<10:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
    n = n+1
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")
    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")
    else:
        print("Got it in "+n+" attempts.")
        n=11
```

Comment: This will just print "Too high" or "Too low" 10 times and never ask for another guess.

Comment: yep, i forgot to move the input too…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you provided has the correct indentation, then it's because the `n = n + 1` statement is outside of the while loop. The corrected code is:

```
import random
name = input("Hello there! What's your name?\n")
print("Hello there", name, ". Welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER GAME")
number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))
n=1
while n<10:
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low")

    elif guess > number:       
        print("Too high")

    elif guess == number:        
        print("Got it")

    n=n+1
```

One piece of advice (assuming you're using Python 2.X): Use `raw_input()` instead of `input`, because `raw_input` automatically parses the input into a string, while `input` allows your users to inject arbitrary python code.

ETA: As pointed out by others, the guess statement (`guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))`) should be moved into the while loop, and a break statement used if the guess is correct.